# How to find all locations in a Java project where a RuntimeException is possible to be thrown?

Tags: java, runtimeexception

I have a java project and I want a list of locations in source code where a RuntimeException might be thrown. Is there any tool or Eclipse plugin to do this?

With FindBugs or PMD the NullPointerExceptions might be located, but I need to locate others as well.

Comment: RuntimeException can be thrown "nearly everywhere". What are you trying to do? (From the javadoc: "RuntimeException is the superclass of those exceptions that can be thrown _during the normal operation of the Java Virtual Machine_.")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NullPointerException, ClassCastException and ArithmeticException  are a special cases as they do not need to be explicitly thrown. However, everything else has to be thrown explicitly.

Searching for possible causes of NullPointerException is useful as its a common bug, however like all RuntimeException they are best avoided rather than handled.  Searching for all possible causes is likely to give you a very large result which is unlikely to be useful. (I have been through this exercise myself and after lots of work didn't achieve much IMHO)

You are better off using code coverage and try edge case values to ensure you have good test cases which are likely to trigger all possible exception instead.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey I guess your suggestion may help. +1

Answer (score 0):

If you're only checking your own code, you can do this with [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/). Look at the [Coding Problems, Illegal Throws](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_coding.html) check.

You can specify any number of Exceptions, by default it is: `java.lang.Throwable, java.lang.Error, java.lang.RuntimeException`.

Note: This doesn't pick up subclasses of the above exceptions, it only picks up the classes themselves. It also does not check source code to which you don't have access, so runtime libraries won't be checked, for instance.

Comment: I don't think this will pick up calls to libraries/JRE which can trigger a RuntimeException.

Comment: @PeterLawrey you're right, it doesn't pick up subclasses of these exceptions, but it does pick up explicit throw new RuntimeException()... Clarified answer.

Comment: But I have not thrown `RuntimeException`s in source code explicitly. Will Checkstyle work in this case?

Comment: @chance No. You need to exactly specify the list.

Comment: @chance, Not unless you use it to check all possible sub-classes of RuntimeException and you check all the source, including the JRE's source.

Comment: Oops. Didn't realise he wanted to check *everywhere*.

Answer (score 0):

I do agree with the other answers. Since I don't know what you want to achieve, I want to offer a more direct answer to your question:

Unfortunately I know no tool that does this. Sorry. Depending on how important it is to you, you could invest some work yourself.

Check your code 'by hand'.

After that the JDK remains (and most likely some libs you are using). You can download the JDKs source code from Oracle. Than you can do a full text search for the occurrences of newly created exception instances again. Note, however, that even this tedious work will not give you all possible sources since some methods are missing there.

Comment: It is not so important. I think the easier way is to check my code 'by hand'.